# put checkboxlist selectedvalue in string in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have checkboxlist in which Item of checkbox & it's value is different. I need to show users item but when it gets submitted it should take selectedItems value. How it can be done?

```
string selectedProducts = string.Empty;
foreach (ListItem chk in productsList.Items) {
    if (chk.Selected == true) {
        selectedProducts += chk.Text + ", ";
    }
}
```

With above code I am getting selectedItem. How can I get selectedItems values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Value` property.

```
string selectedProducts = string.Empty;
foreach (ListItem chk in productsList.Items) {
    if (chk.Selected == true) {
        selectedProducts += chk.Value+ ", ";
    }
}
```

Comment: @PhiterFernandes I did but there was not simple solution given like Leopard did.

Comment: But I'm sure google would give you the simplest of the solutions, which is the simple usage of `Value`

Comment: @PhiterFernandes you can search on google. There were solution which was large lines of codes & no value hint given any of them